# ¿Qué son "derechos de anato"?

Tags: definiciones, historia, méxico

En los [Archivos Históricos del Arzobispado de Durango](http://lib.nmsu.edu/archives/documents/ahad.pdf) hay tal documento:

> Renuncia del arcediano, Agustín Fernández San Vicente, de los derechos de
>   anato de la iglesia de Durango

No hé podido comprender aún lo que es un derecho de anato. ¿Qué será?

Comment: Supongo que el espacio es una errata y se refiere a : [deanato](http://dle.rae.es/?id=BtUI7If)

Comment: He buscado en el documento que enlazas en la pregunta y aparece *deanato* varias veces en el texto. Aunque lo de *anata* también podía ser

Comment: Sospecho que se pueda referir al cobro de la anata. Los sacerdotes de una diocesis aportaban durante su primer año la mitad de su sueldo y en los años siguientes un diezmo, para los gastos de la diócesis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El "anato" es el nombre que se daba al pago como impuestos de la mitad del salario del primer año a cambio de la concesión de un cargo.

En la Iglesia se aplicaba el mismo concepto para el mantenimiento de la diócesis y la curia.

https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anata_(impuesto)

Comment: ¿Bajo esta interpretación, el transcriptor erró al colocar la forma masculina?

Comment: Lo ignoro, pero es posible que se refiera al derecho de cobro de la anata de la mencionada iglesia. Otro término similar es el de "mesada",  que se refiere al pago del salario de un mes.

Answer (score 3):

El [arcedianato](http://dle.rae.es/?id=3Ry4US1) es la dignidad del cargo de [arcediano](http://dle.rae.es/?id=3S2sKeX) (también conocido como [archidiácono](http://dle.rae.es/?id=3SNPOCh)).

Similarmente, el [deanato](http://dle.rae.es/?id=BtUI7If) (a veces [decanato](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Bv99zCB)) es la dignidad del cargo de [deán](http://dle.rae.es/?id=BtSFzGY).

Es posible que se utilizase "anato" como nombre genérico para las dignidades eclesiásticas: deanatos, vicedeanatos, arcedianatos, etc. En tal caso, **"derecho de anato" sería el derecho a ostentar un cargo eclesiástico**, y el texto vendría a querer decir que el arcediano renunció a ostentar dicho cargo.

---

También puede ser (yo lo veo más probable) que el documento sea una mala transcripción donde se han fusionado dos "de":

> *Renuncia del arcediano, Agustín Fernández San Vicente, de los derechos **de** **de**anato de la iglesia de Durango*

Comment: Ya que no hay evidencia que apoye la primera idea, debe ser el caso la segunda. Gracias.

Comment: El deanato o decanato no es ningún "derecho" y dudo que sea una errata.